# Query to show all column, table and schema names together in IMPALA

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala

I want to get metadata of impala db in one query. Probably It will be like

```
SELECT columnname,tablename,schemaname from SYSTEM.INFO
```

Is there a way to do that? and I dont want to fetch only current tables columns for example;

```
SHOW COLUMN STATS db.table_name
```

This query is not answer of my question. I want to select all metadata in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `impala-shell` you have commands like:

`describe table_name`

`describe formatted table_name`

`describe database_name`

`EXPLAIN { select_query | ctas_stmt | insert_stmt }`

and the `SHOW Statement` that is a flexible way to get information about different types of Impala objects. You can follow this link to the `Impala documentation` [SHOW statement](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_show.html#show).

On the other hand, information about the schema objects is held in the metastore database. This database is shared between Impala and Hive.

In particular, Impala keeps its table definitions in a traditional `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL` database known as the `metastore`, the same database where Hive keeps this type of data. Thus, Impala can access tables defined or loaded by Hive, as long as all columns use Impala-supported data types, file formats, and compression codecs.

If you want to query this information in one shot you would have to query to `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `Oracle`, or etc, it's depending on your particular case.

For example, in my case `Impala` keeps `metadata` in `MySQL`.

```sql
use metastore;
-- Database changed
SHOW tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_metastore       |
+---------------------------+
| BUCKETING_COLS            |
| CDS                       |
| COLUMNS_V2                |
| COMPACTION_QUEUE          |
| COMPLETED_TXN_COMPONENTS  |
| DATABASE_PARAMS           |
| DBS                       |
.......
........
| TAB_COL_STATS             |
| TBLS                      |
| TBL_COL_PRIVS             |
| TBL_PRIVS                 |
| TXNS                      |
| TXN_COMPONENTS            |
| TYPES                     |
| TYPE_FIELDS               |
| VERSION                   |
+---------------------------+
54 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM VERSION;

+--------+----------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
| VER_ID | SCHEMA_VERSION | VERSION_COMMENT            | SCHEMA_VERSION_V2 |
+--------+----------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
|      1 | 1.1.0          | Hive release version 1.1.0 | 1.1.0-cdh5.12.0   |
+--------+----------------+----------------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope this helps.